# Error: Deallocating a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I am developing a program in which one of the task is to read points (x,y and z) from a text file and then store them in an array. Now the text file may contain 10^2 or even 10^6 points, depending upon the text file user selects. Therefore I am defining a dynamic array.

For allocating a dynamic 2D array, I wrote as below and it works fine:

```
const int array_size = 100000;
float** array = new float* [array_size]; 
for(int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i){
    ary[i] = new float[2]; // 0,1,2 being the columns for x,y,z co-ordinates
}
```

After the points are saved in the array, I write the following to deallocate the unallocated memory :

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
    delete [] array[i];
}

delete [] array;
```

and then my program stops working and shows "Project.exe stopped working".

If I don't deallocate, the program works just fine.

Comment: Do you have some compelling reason to not use `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: On that same note, why not just make an array of a `struct` containing 3 floats?

Comment: You have a typo `ary[i] = new float[2];` ary => array

Comment: The code you wrote here is ok, why don't you paste the real one?

Comment: @adrin is on the right track. You are clobbering memory if you think you can assign 3 values (0,1,2) to a an array of 2. That is likely what is causing your `delete []` to fail. I assume one iteration always succeeds.

Comment: You could avoid allocating a bunch of arrays and use a one dimensional array and calculate data[ i * 3 + j ] - maybe deallocation of 100000 elements is just too slow

Comment: @shuttle87 I am restraining to use vector because (I read somewhere) it uses unnecessary processing power when one uses "push" to increase the initially defined vector size. Is that right?

Comment: @shuttle87 Regarding array, I doubt it is dynamic. Since the variation of array size is too high and very unpredictable, I need to use dynamic array.

Comment: @deepak09027: Is it dynamic or not? The language you have used is highly confusing.

Comment: @shuttle87. Sorry for confusing language but what I mean is exactly as below:

Comment: @shuttle87. Sorry for confusing language but what I mean exactly is : 1) I want to use a dynamic array as the variation in my array  size is huge. 2) I remember reading it somewhere that one has to use "push" and "pop" methods (defined in vector class) to insert elements beyond initially defined vector size, which takes considerable processing time as address of other elements stored in vector are also changed after a push.

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't reallocate memory after every single `push_back`. I'd suggest looking at a tutorial such as this one: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm

Comment: @shuttle87 Thanx that link was very useful. Although after each push_back is used, it does seem to reallocate.

Answer (score 2):

In your comment you say `0,1,2 being the columns for x,y,z co-ordinates`, if that's the case, you need to be allocating as `float[3]`. When you allocate an array of `float[N]`, you are allocating a chunk of the memory of the size `N * sizeof(float)`, and you will index them in the array from `1` to `N - 1`. Therefore if you need indeces `0,1,2`, you will need to allocate a memory of the size `3 * sizeof(float)`, which makes it `float[3]`.

Because other than that, I can compile and run the code without an error. If you fix it and still get an error, it might be your compiler problem. Then try to decrease `100000` to a small number and try again.

Comment: Don't think the compiler can be the problem here.

Comment: I agree that in such a case you can rely on the compiler, but I suspected the compiler is Turbo C here :D

Comment: @adrin I am using Dev C++ as IDE and the compiler being used is TDM-GCC 4.7.1.

Comment: So did you figure out the problem?

Comment: @adrin Can you tell me why to use float[3] instead of float[2]? Sorry , but I am new to C++ and used to program in Matlab before this.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that you are trying to implement a dynamic array, this is what `std::vector` does and I would highly recommend that you use it. This way you are using something from the standard library that's extremely well tested and you won't run into issues by essentially trying to roll your own version of `std::vector`. Additionally this approach wraps memory better as it uses RAII which leverages the language to solve a lot of memory management issues. This has other benefits too like making your code more exception safe.

Also if you are storing x,y,z coordinates consider using a struct or a tuple, I think that enhances readability a lot. You can typedef the coordinate type too. Something like `std::vector< coord_t >` is more readable to me.

Comment: But I read somewhere that for increasing the size of a vector, values are pushed at the back of the vector and it requires extra processing.

Comment: If you know in advance how many elements are in the array you can use `std::vector`s `reserve` member function to pre-allocate the size. If you want a dynamic array you will find that there's always going to be an overhead to resizing the array, that's just intrinsic to the problem. If the array is always going to be the same size then you can use `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

(Thanx a lot for suggestions!!)

Finally I am using vectors for the stated problem for reasons as below:

1.Unlike Arrays (not array object ofcourse), I don't need to manually deallocate unallocated memory.

2.There are numerous built in methods defined under vector class

1. Vector size can be extended at later stages

Below is how I used 2D Vector to store points (x,y,z co-ordinates)

Initialized (allocated memory) a 2D vector:

```
          vector<vector<float>> array (1000, vector<float> array (3));
```

Where 1000 is the number of rows, and 3 is the number of columns

Once declared, values can be passed simply as:

```
                      array[i][j] = some value;
```

Also, at later stage I declared functions taking vector arguments and returning vectors  as:

```
          vector <vector <float>> function_name ( vector <vector <float>>);

   vector <vector <float>> function_name ( vector <vector <float>> input_vector_name)

   {

    return output_vector_name_created_inside_function

   }
```

Note: This method crates a copy of vector while returning, use pointer to return by reference. Even though mine is not working when I return vector by reference :(

Answer (score -1):

For multi arrays I recommended use [boost::multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).
Example:

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);
A[0][0][0] = 3.14;
```